# As of April 2023, is preregistration required prior to visiting sites like Mecca and Medina during Umrah?

Tags: saudi-arabia, mecca, medina

I will be visiting Mecca and Medina in early May 2023 for Umrah. Is preregistration mandatory to perform Umrah in Mecca as well as for visiting various religious sites in Medina and Mecca? I’ve seen conflicting information on YouTube as to whether the Nusuk app is required.

Also, when do they check for proof of religion (like having to show an Islam conversion certificate)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to register for Umrah on the Nusuk App

The [site](https://www.nusuk.sa/rituals) states :

> Pilgrims must perform Umrah at the time allotted to them, according to their reservations on the official Umrah apps.

> Those entering the Kingdom on any type of visa can go to Makkah to perform Umrah after making a reservation through the Nusuk app.